# Check lastInsertId() before relying on it

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What is a good way to check that lastInsertId() returns true and a number (the id)?

(PDO using mySQL database)

Do I need to do something like this?

```
// some INSERT query here

$lastid = $conn->lastInsertId();

if (is_numeric($lastid) && $lastid > 0) {

  // ok, NOW you can use $lastid

}
```

Or is there a simpler (perhaps native) way?

Comment: Could post more details?

Comment: well first of all are you using PDO mysql or mysqli, second what did you expect to get when you used lastinsertId() and what are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Did you received any errors?

Comment: I dont get what you dont understand.. The question says it quite good. Errors? Thats not the issue.. Im looking for the right/simplest/native way to check if lastInsertId() actually returned a number (id). So I'm expecting a number over 0. And lastInsertId() is PDO only so I dont understand your question about that either.. (mysql/mysqli is mysql_insert_id / mysqli::$insert_id), but to clarify: it's PDO, using a mySQL database

Comment: on mysql, it's just doing `select last_insert_id();`, essentially. that function'll return `0` if no insert was performed. it doesn't return a null or a failure. it's either 0, or the id of the last insert. If you have a degenerate case of signed IDs and forced mysql to start numbering in the negatives, then you COULD get a false 0 when the `0` id naturally does come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) returns a string, typical numeric. Because of the difference among the database drivers, this may not even return anything meaningful, states the documentation.

I cast it to an `int` and just check to see if it's 0.

```
$lastid = (int) $conn->lastInsertId();

if (!$lastid) 
{
   // Failed retrieving the ID (but didn't necessarily fail the insert)
}
```

Comment: "Failed retrieving the ID (but didn't necessarily fail the insert)" is excactly what I'm aiming at.. anything can happen. Nice solution, thanks